# Записать в базу текст из динамически созданных textbox- ов

Tags: c#, xml

Одной кнопкой я создаю динамические массивы, введя их количество во второй текстбокс

```
for (int i = 0, x = 1; i < int.Parse(textBox2.Text); i++, x++)
    {
        TextBox dynamicTextBox = new TextBox() { Parent = panel1 };

        dynamicTextBox.Name = x.ToString();
        dynamicTextBox.Location = new Point(40, 210 + i * 30);
        dynamicTextBox.AppendText(dynamicTextBox.Text + "\r\n");
    }
```

Как записать их в базу xml совсем другой кнопкой? Спасибо!
Примерно так выглядит база xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <nameAnketa>анкета1</nameAnketa>
  <Priznak>(ФИО, пол, возраст и т.д.)</Priznak>
  <vopros>Вы пойдете на выборы президента РФ 2018?</vopros>
  <nameVariants>да/нет</nameVariants>
</NewDataSet>
```

Благодарю всех за помощь! Вроде получилось разобраться. Прилагаю код с пометками

```
List<TextBox> AllDynamicTextbox = new List<TextBox>();//переменная List, где хранятся все созданные textbox -ы
        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)//кнопка создания textbox -ов
        {
        for (int i = 0, x = 1; i < int.Parse(textBox2.Text); i++, x++)//цикл и парсинг количества textbox -ов
        {
                AllDynamicTextbox.Add(new TextBox());
                AllDynamicTextbox[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(600, (210 + i * 20));//положение на форме
                this.Controls.Add(AllDynamicTextbox[i]);//добавили на форму 

            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//запись в базу
        {
          for (int i = 0; i < AllDynamicTextbox.Count; i++)
                {
                    string text = AllDynamicTextbox[i].Text;
                    XmlElement Variants = doc.CreateElement("variants");//создали новый элемент в xml базе
                    Variants.InnerText = text;//записали в него все значения из textbox -ов
                    doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(Variants);//добавили в базу
                }
        }
```

В xml выглядит так(было создано 4 динамических textbox -ов с текстом 1,2,3,4):

```
  <variants>1</variants>
  <variants>2</variants>
  <variants>3</variants>
  <variants>4</variants>
```

Comment: Под записью в xml вы имеете в виду добавление новых значений?

Comment: Да, сначала в базу

Comment: А не могли бы вы примерную структуру xml файла добавить?

Comment: добавил примерную структуру базы

Comment: Ваш вопрос нужно разделить на два: 1. как работать с динамически создаваемыми контролами; 2. как создать xml.

Comment: Получить список ранее добавленных текстбоксов можно следующим образом: `panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сохраняйте ваши текстбоксы в глобальную переменную, в качестве которой может использоваться `List<TextBox>`.

В обработчике другой кнопки обращайтесь к ранее сформированному `List<TextBox>`.

UPD: Как верно заметил @Сергей, достаточно, чтобы переменная была видна членами класса.

Comment: Ну с глобальной переменной ты погорячился, скажем так - выше по уровню видимости откуда она будет видна другим членам класса =)

Comment: Listbox сделал, не совсем пойму как к нему можно обратиться

Comment: @Python_noob Здесь есть информация по использованию коллекции List. https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/4.5.php